# Create multidimensional array from three arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three arrays with the same number of items, where the values can be identical inside each array and between arrays.

```
$areas
0 => 1
1 => 3
2 => 3
3 => 5

$targets
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 3

$ratings 
0 => 1
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 3
```

I want to create a multidimensional array ($elements) that shows the values of $ratings by accessing the values of $areas and $targets as keys.

```
Example: 
$elements[area][target] = rating
$elements[1][1] = 1
$elements[3][2] = 1
$elements[3][3] = 2
$elements[5][3] = 3
```

I have tried a lot of functions to flip and merge the arrays, but is struggling for many reasons, but mostly because when flipping the identical values makes
the number of items differ between the arrays.

Can anyone help me to achieve what I want?

Comment: You will run into the problem, that keys must be unique!

Comment: The best I have come up with is to start with $elements = array_flip($areas), then make the values of this array null. Which gives me $elements 1=>null, 3=>null, 5=>null. 
From there, I need a way to add the relevant target id's to the corresponding area id, but I have not come up with a way to do this.

The reason I did not post this attempt is that I assume there must be a better way that I have not thought of, I am sorry.

Comment: @Bergkamp10 Your first problem is, that you can't have duplicate keys, so you can't get your expected output, it will never work

Answer (score 0):

You would never really want to use this construction as you're basically trying to use numeric keys that might not be set. All the missing keys will be filled up anyways but you won't get the end value (maybe an empty string or null if you're lucky).

I would advise you to look at this from a different angle because there is simply no proper explanation for doing it exactly that way with such values.

My suggestion would be to read up on [php associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

As this type of array is very often used when creating multidementional arrays.
In this array you basically set `key => value` pairs and because you can use strings as keys it's easy to create an array that makes sense e.g.

```
$people = array(
    array(
        'firstname' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Doe',
        'age' => 29,
        'sex' => 'Male'
        //etc...
    );
);
```

now if you would loop over the main array you would get an array back with those `key => value` pairs and these give you some good information rather than jumping hoops with alot of numbers ;)

Hope it helps,
Sidney